# Jenkins build issue for SFRA

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins

Hi SFCC Developers,

I am facing an issue while doing a build through Jenkins. (We are using Jenkins for CI.)

I have followed a same steps which we follow for compilation through our local machines.

We are executing following command in "execute shell script" step of Jenkins and then using "OSF builder plugin", we are uploading the code to development and staging instance:-

echo -----SFRA BASE CARTRIDGE-----

cd storefront-reference-architecture

rm -rf node_modules

npm install sgmf-scripts

npm install

echo ###COMPILING SCSS###

npm run compile:scss

echo ###SCSS COMPILATION COMPLETED###

echo ###COMPILING JAVASCRIPT###

npm run compile:js

echo ###JAVASCRIPT COMPILED###

echo ###COMPILING FONTS###

npm run compile:fonts

echo ###FONTS COMPILED###

Observed that we are getting an error as "Cleave is not a constructor". However in "node_modules" i can see a folder created for cleave. We are using node version 10.14.2 and npm version 6.4.1 and on jenkins we are using npm version 6.12.1.

Any idea what can be possible reasons because of which we are facing this issue? Please help.

What is the standard or best practices for SFRA build through Jenkins.